# Paint stroke bug

Tags: android, canvas, paint, stroke

When I draw Path on the bitmap, it will draw not only Red stroke but also a dark Red stroke inner and that is, I think a drawing bug

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setFlags(Paint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.HINTING_ON | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setDither(true);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStrokeWidth(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.overlay_stroke_width));
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Here is the screen

[image: Draw path]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are redrawing the path with another Paint, you have to draw the red stroke drawPath after draw the **fill path**